# How can i create a CRUD form in JavaFx which is connected with database

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I want to build a Crud Form(Create,Read,Update,Delete) in JavaFX with Scene Builder,so i have two combo boxes and one text field where i write the quantity,so when i create an order(first combo box is for number of table the second is for the type of food)and when i press create order,i want that all these to be in table view which is connected with database.

```
  final ObservableList options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  public void addButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

          try {
                prequery="SELECT * FROM product_table where artikulli='"+comboBoxOrder.getValue();
                postquery=prequery;
                pst= con.prepareStatement(postquery);
                rs=pst.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                    options.add(new AddOrderTableView(
                            rs.getInt("No"),
                            rs.getInt("Qty"),
                            rs.getString("Item"),
                            rs.getInt("Price")
                            ));

                }

                pst.close();
                rs.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }

            col_no.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("No"));
            col_qty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Qty"));
            col_item.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Item"));
            col_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));
            addOrder_Table.setItems(null);
            addOrder_Table.setItems(options);

        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code?

Comment: This is too broad for SO. You need to try something. Make an effort and we will help you with problems in your code.

Comment: What code? I don't see any.

Comment: @ManoDestra i tried this

Comment: How is the db table defined? Do you need to retrieve the values you just inserted from the db? Also where does the price come from (1 `TextField` (Qty) + 2 `ComboBox`es (`NO`, `Item`))? Furthermore what exactly is the issue here. The insert statement won't work that way but I'm almost sure there are other questions "hidden somewhere between the lines". Please add a clear problem statement. Currently this question seems a bit too broad, since it could involve multiple things (creating the table, adding values to a query properly, retrieving the values just added to the db, ...)

Comment: @fabian yes,i want to retrieve the values,the price is in db.So i made a db with No,Qty,Item and Price and in ComboBox i call just the Item than when i press for example Add Order the data of this  ComboBox have to bo inserted in tableView.My first db is product_table(product_id,article and price) so this is in one comboBox(Item),and when inesert this comboBox in tableView this data have to be inserted in another db(Add_NewOrderDB)that stores data

Comment: If the entry is already in the db, why are you using an `INSERT` query? This should either be `SELECT` or a `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @fabian thats why im asking ,because i think i did a mess there and now im out of ideas

Comment: @fabian can u show me a piece of code just to refer me,the rest ill do it myself